# Why this code permanently delete not move to junk folder? VB.NET VSTO Outlook Add-In

Tags: vb.net, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

```
   objSelection = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection
   objJunkFolder = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderJunk)
   For Each objMail In objSelection
      If TypeOf objMail Is MailItem Then
         objMail.Move(objJunkFolder)
      End If
   Next
```

Make mail item move to junk folder